# Strange Angular 2/JS Error: "Cannot use keyword 'catch' as Identifier"?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Teaching myself Angular 2.

Everything was working fine, suddenly this error appeared out of the blue:

```
Multiple Annotations found at this line:
  -Cannot use keyword 'import' as Identifier
  -Cannot use keyword 'catch' as Identifier.
```

Here's a screen-grab of the offending line:

[image: screen-grab of a strange error message that suddenly appeared:]

And now this HTML page loads blank in the browser. (Well, its not completely blank: it does display the ***name*** of the .html file I'm trying to open - that name appears as the only content on this web page - and that's it. The page is otherwise just white background.

Any clues what's going on here? 
(Note this bit of code where the error is happening is not even my code; its template code that came with the file. And as I already mentioned, everything ***was*** working perfectly fine - until this error suddenly appeared out of nowhere...)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

==========================

**UPDATE** - Adding both the full HTML file and the `systemjs.config.js` file - which I haven't even touched:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Here's the full HTML doc:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 Demo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>System.import('app').catch(function(err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <subscription-form></subscription-form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: look at your systemjs.config.js, there might be some changes you have done.

Comment: I haven't touched the `systemjs.config.js` file - but I copy pasted it into the body of the question above in case people want to see what might be wrong there...